# Restoring data using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, storage

I have a saving method that runs during `onPause()`:

```
    String save = numberValue.getText().toString();
    FileInputStream fos;

    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(save.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Save has run", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and I try to read this file by calling

```
new Loader().execute(FILENAME);
```

and my Loader class looks like this:

```
public class Loader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textview.setText(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        String loaded = null;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
            byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
            while (fis.read(dataArray) != -1) {
                loaded = new String(dataArray);
            }
            fis.close();
            textview.setText(loaded);
            return loaded;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return loaded;
    }

}
```

And I have no idea as to why the textview does not get set as the bytes from FILENAME. The idea is that the textview is an increasing number, and this number gets saved when the activity is closed and gets restored to the textview when the activity starts up again.

It does start, I know that because after a few minutes, Watch Dog tells me that a background service from this app is consuming about 50% of CPU. I did check /data/data//files and the file that I write to is there with the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to call your `Loader` from `onResume()` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save the state you need by using the [onSavedInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) method? Writing stuff out to the fileSystem on the onPause method is going to making switching out of your application really slow. From the [Activity Documentation regarding the onPause method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity. This is typically used to commit unsaved changes to persistent data, stop animations and other things that may be consuming CPU, etc. Implementations of this method must be very quick because the next activity will not be resumed until this method returns.

Also, from the android documentation:

> In situations where the system needs more memory it may kill paused processes to reclaim resources. Because of this, you should be sure that all of your state is saved by the time you return from this function. In general onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is used to save per-instance state in the activity and this method is used to store global persistent data (in content providers, files, etc.)

[Here's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) where I got that from.

Comment: I need the data to save when the user backs out of the activity, not when the system decides to kill it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what ever your text view is displaying at the time will stay in there then if your activity is just paused.